# How can I pull updates from a force-pushed branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push, git-fetch

I aim to minimise commits on each merge request. To achieve this I rebase locally before pushing to the MR and, if required, rebase against "old" MR commits and force-push the result. (I obviously don't rebase against commits already in master).

If I need to update on a testing environment I can't do this:

```
git pull
```

...because of the force-push. So instead I do this:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git branch -D feature_branch
git checkout feature_branch  # now includes force-pushed changes
```

Obviously I could write my own script/hook to do this in one step. Is way to update a local branch (when I know the remote copy has been force-pushed) with fewer **built-in** steps?

Comment: If your goal is simply to get a current copy of `feature_branch`, you can simply (assuming your work tree is already on `feature_branch`) `git remote update; git reset --hard origin/feature_branch`.

Comment: Besides the answer from @larsks, consider not having and using a (local) branch at all: just use detached-HEAD mode to check out and use the `origin/feature_branch` commit. When `git fetch` or `git remote update` updates the `origin/feature_branch` commit, use another `git checkout` to switch to that one.

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
git fetch origin +feature_branch:feature_branch
```

This updates branch `feature_branch` in the local repository by fetching from the `feature_branch` branch in the remote repository.

The `+` symbol is key in that it means the `feature_branch` will be updated even if it does not fast-forward (which is typically (always?) the case with a force-pushed branch)